# Linq for xml parsing returns null element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<roulette xmlns="Mechanical" name="Ruleta">
  <params name="Mechanical Counters">
    <param name="C01">
      <comm>30313</comm>
      <command>INA</command>
      <factor>5</factor>
      <index>2</index>
      <meter>0</meter>
      <player>1023</player>
      <meterstring>ml_BET</meterstring>
    </param>
    <param name="C02">
      <comm>30313</comm>
      <command>INC</command>
      <factor>5</factor>
      <index>3</index>
      <meter>0</meter>
      <player>1023</player>
      <meterstring>ml_WIN_PAYTABLE</meterstring>
    </param>
    <param name="C03">
      <comm>30313</comm>
      <command>INE</command>
      <factor>5</factor>
      <index>0</index>
      <meter>0</meter>
      <player>1023</player>
      <meterstring>ml_CRE_IN_BA + ml_CRE_IN_REM + ml_CRE_IN_KEY + ml_CRE_IN_TICKET</meterstring>
    </param>
    <param name="C04">
      <comm>30313</comm>
      <command>ING</command>
      <factor>5</factor>
      <index>1</index>
      <meter>0</meter>
      <player>1023</player>
      <meterstring>ml_CRE_OUT_KEY + ml_CRE_OUT_HANDPAY + ml_CRE_OUT_HANDPAYJP + ml_CRE_OUT_REM + ml_CRE_OUT_TICKET</meterstring>
    </param>
    <param name="Percentage">
      <factor>10</factor>
    </param>
    <param name="WaitAnswer">
      <miliseconds>2500</miliseconds>
    </param>
  </params>
</roulette>
```

I am trying to parse out a `comm` element of the parent `param` element where name equals to C01 to display it in a textbox.

My code looks like this:

```
private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //loadamo xml dokument
            var doc = XDocument.Load("mechanical.xml");
            //preberemo prvi element števca C01 comm
            var prvi = doc.Descendants("param")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "C01")
    .Elements("comm")
    .FirstOrDefault();
            if (prvi != null) { textBox1.Text = "Je element"; } else { textBox1.Text = "ni elementa"; }


        }
```

The problem is that it parses me out nothing ( the var `prvi` is null ) but it shouldn't supposed to the code. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xml has a default namespace `xmlns="Mechanical"`. To access the elements you must to specify the namespace.

```
XNamespace ns = "Mechanical";

var prvi = doc.Descendants(ns + "param")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "C01")
    .Elements(ns + "comm")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that default namespaces do not apply directly to attributes.

See [Namespace Defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) for more information.

Comment: Tnx, now is perfectly working! When i am viewing a xml file where can i see that it has a namespace?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the help, really helped me out man!