# Update XML file with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationConfiguration xmlns="http://test.org/SDK/Configuration.xsd">
    <ApplicationName>
        <ApplicationUri>123</ApplicationUri>
        <ApplicationUri>456</ApplicationUri>
    </ApplicationName>
</ApplicationConfiguration>
```

What I want is set the value of `ApplicationUri` from 456 to 789 in C# code.

I wrote this code:

```
string docaddress = "testfile.xml";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(docaddress);
doc.Element("ApplicationConfiguration")
            .Elements("ApplicationName").FirstOrDefault()
            .SetElementValue("ApplicationUri", "789");
doc.Save(docaddress);
```

The problems are:

1. There is no error while running. I think the element `ApplicationConfiguration` is not correct. But when I delete the line `xmlns=...` from the xml file, it runs normally
2. The value `789` is replaced with `123`, but not `456` as I want (same element name)

Can you tell me how to fix those problems?

Comment: You say there's an error, but what is it? This `.Elements("ApplicationName").FirstOrDefault()
            .SetElementValue("ApplicationUri", "789");` says set the value of the first element. So if there are multiple, it will only update the first one.

Comment: 1)Here's the error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) returned null.

Comment: 2) So isn't there any way to set the value of the second element?

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` picks the first element in a list, i.e. 123. If you want to change all elements you need to loop over them.

Comment: You must take into account the namespace. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38168503/5045688)

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

The xmlns attribute on the ApplicationConfiguration element makes that the root.
So you get the root first. Then you replace the values of each descendant, selecting locally by name with the element name you want. something like this:

```
 string docaddress = "C:\\temp\\testfile.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(docaddress);
        var root = doc.Root;
        var descendants = root.Descendants();
        var these = root.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "ApplicationUri");
        foreach (var elem in these)
        {
            elem.Value = "789";

        }  
        doc.Save(docaddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, here is an easiest method.

It is taking care of the XML default namespace.

No loops. Set based approach.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\hala.xml";
    const string searchFor = "456";
    const string replaceWith = "789";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    // step #1: find element based on the search value
    XElement xmlFragment = doc.Descendants(ns + "ApplicationUri")
        .Where(d => d.Value.Equals(searchFor)).FirstOrDefault();

    // step #2: if found, set its value 
    if(xmlFragment != null)
        xmlFragment.SetValue(replaceWith);

    doc.Save(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added namespace to your code :

```
            string docaddress = "testfile.xml";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(docaddress);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            doc.Element(ns + "ApplicationConfiguration")
                        .Elements(ns + "ApplicationName").FirstOrDefault()
                        .SetElementValue(ns + "ApplicationUri", "789");
            doc.Save(docaddress);
```